# PostgreSQL: Is it possible to use the result of a subquery into a jsonb?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a query that gets some data, for example:

```
select type_of_client from table1;    

type_of_client
--------------
  restaurant
  bar
  cinema
  ...
```

And I would like to use these results into a jsonb element, for example:

```
select count(*) from table2 where fields->>'restaurant' is null;
select count(*) from table2 where fields->>'bar' is null;
select count(*) from table2 where fields->>'cinema' is null;


Expected results:
10
20
5
```

Is it possible?
I need to make it dynamically because there are a lot of type_of_clients at table_1

Comment: It clearly _is_ possible to use the result of a query into a jsonb, yet your question is completely unclear to me. Some details/examples/expected results pls.?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I would like to use something like:
select fields->>'(select type_of_client from table1)' from table;

But its not possible

Comment: @devinho What are the values of `fields` in `table2`? What is the expected output of your query?

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my question, I need to get a count using the results of table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, the `->` operator can take any expression of type `text` as its second operand, not just literals. You can use a subquery (if it returns 0 to 1 rows with a single column, not more):

```
select fields->>(select type_of_client from table1) from table2;
```

or you might be looking for a cross join:

```
select type_of_client, field->>type_of_client from table1, table2;
```

or for your use case:

```
SELECT type_of_client, count(*) FILTER (WHERE field->>type_of_client IS NULL) FROM table1, table2 GROUP BY type_of_client;
SELECT type_of_client, (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE field->>type_of_client IS NULL) AS count FROM table1;
```

Comment: Great Bergi, your full explanation abaout jsonb helped me a lot, I didn't know that was possible to pass a subquery in it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why one would do such a thing, but technically

```sql
select (jsonb_object_agg(type_of_client, type_of_client))->>'restaurant' from table1;
```

does match your example.

There are a few useful row_to_json(b) functions, as well as other jsonb aggregations functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.12.1.1.1

Comment: `jsonb_object_agg(type_of_client, type_of_client)` doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: no it doesn't, I agree :) but I see what they mean now, your answer is the correct one where they use the column value as the ->> field access